# Insert values without duplicates

Tags: mariadb, rdbms

I want to add payment type 3 to all businesses. How may i do it with MariaDB.

I do like this:

```
insert into business_payment_type 
        (id_payment_type, active) 
    select "4", "1" 
    from business_payment_type 
    where id_business in (select distinct(id_business) 
                          from business_payment_type)
```

But it return error:

> 1364 - Field 'id_business' doesn't have a default value

Table like on image

[image: my table image]

Comment: From that image, that looks like PHPMyAdmin, which suggests you're using MySQL, not SQl Server. Please do only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: On a side note: Why `"1"`? Is `active` a text column? I'd rather expect it to be a numeric column, so I'd use `4` without quotes instead. And when really dealing with string literals, you should use standard single quotes, e.g. `'a string'`, not double quotes (which are name delimiters in the SQL standard).

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner . Yes i understood my mistake. Unfortunately did not pay an attention

Comment: Are you looking for the `UPDATE` statement?  Or `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN`?

Comment: Or `INSERT IGNORE` with a unique key (possibly composite)?

Comment: Actually not new column but new row in my case, @RickJames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all of your `id_business` values and your new values together in one statement, then `INSERT` that record set into your table.

```
INSERT INTO business_payment_type (
   id_business
  ,id_payment_type
  ,active
  )
SELECT DISTINCT
  id_business
  ,4 AS id_payment_type
  ,1 AS active
FROM business_payment_type;
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But i tried almost the same thing and got error also. I did like that:
insert into business_payment_type ("id_business", "id_business_type", "active") select distinct(id_business), "4", "1" from business_payment_type

Comment: MySQL syntax allows you to use `DISTINCT` like that, but it doesn't return the results your expect, as you saw. `DISTINCT` isn't a function, and it can't be applied to a column that way, really. I'm glad this worked. Please consider marking this as your accepted answer by clicking on the grey check mark on the left. We'll each earn a few reputation points if you do, and others will be able to see that you found a solution.

Comment: Thakn you for explanation also Mr. Eric

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add payment type 3 to all businesses.

All businesses are probably in the business table. Hence:

```
insert into business_payment_type (id_business, id_payment_type, active) 
  select id_business, 3, 1 from business;
```

Comment: I tried something this also but unfortunately  due to inattendance got some errors and could not solve the problem. Thank you